# Strange acting of CUDA for large amount of threads

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to prepare my CUDA kernels for working over large amount of particles (much exceeding 65535 which is max value of gridDim). I tried to create a proper thread index mapping working for any `<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>` values.

I wrote this:

```
__global__ void step_k(float* position, size_t numElements, unsigned int* blabla) 
{   
    unsigned int i = calculateIndex();

    if (i < numElements){
        blabla[i] = i;
    }
}

__device__ unsigned int calculateIndex(){
    unsigned int xIndex = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIndex = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int zIndex = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z+threadIdx.z;

    unsigned int xSize = gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
    unsigned int ySize = gridDim.y*blockDim.y;

    return xSize*ySize*zIndex+xSize*yIndex+xIndex;
}
```

and I use it this way:

```
void CudaSphFluids::step(void)
{
    //dim3 threadsPerBlock(1024, 1024, 64);
    //dim3 numBlocks(65535, 65535, 65535);

    dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 256, 1);

    unsigned int result[256] = {};
    unsigned int* d_results;
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_results,sizeof(unsigned int)*256);

    step_k<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_position, 256, d_results);

    cudaMemcpy(result,d_results,sizeof(unsigned int)*256,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    CLOG(INFO, "SPH")<<"STEP";
    for(unsigned int t=0; t<256;t++) {
        cout<<result[t]<<"; ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cudaFree(d_results);
    Sleep(200);
}
```

It seems to be ok (incrementing numbers from 0 to 255) for :

```
dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 1, 1);
```

It works for:

```
dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 3, 1);
```

but when I try to run it for:

```
dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 5, 1);
```

[image]

for:

```
dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 10, 1);
```

[image]

and for larger values like:

```
dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 256, 1);
```

it's getting crazy:

[image]

Then I tried to use another mapping from some smart guy's website:

```
__device__ int getGlobalIdx_3D_3D()
{
int blockId = blockIdx.x 
 + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x 
 + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; 
int threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z)
  + (threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y))
  + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x)
  + threadIdx.x;
return threadId;
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. (numbers are different, but also wrong).

Any ideas what is the reason of such a strange acting?

I use CUDA 6.0 on GeForce GTX 560Ti (sm_21) and VS2012 with NSight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is requesting 65536 threads per block:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 256, 1);
```

That is not acceptable on any current CUDA GPU, which are [limited to either 512 or 1024 threads per block](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications).

These are also launching too many threads per block:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 5, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256, 10, 1);
```

Start by adding [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your program.  I would suggest doing this on any CUDA code before posting here.  You will be more informed, and others will be able to help you better.

Although you don't show your complete kernel, your kernel indexing seems to be set up correctly for 3D indexing.  Therefore, it may just be a matter of also modifying this line:

```
dim3 numBlocks(1, 1, 1);
```

Which you will probably want to do to get reasonable performance out of the GPU.

Comment: Thank you. That seems legit. I thought this max value is for one dimension of thread block, not total amount of them. I'll add error checking as well. (I'll accept answer in 5 minutes, it's blocked now).